Notion API retrieve all outermost files
Is there a way to retrieve all the outtermost parents? Right now I recursively call search but that can't be it.
It takes way too long to recursively call search, I can easily get the children if I have a given parent ID. but the issue is I have no way to get these parent IDs. If anyone could help me that would be great.
Here's the code I have:
func ListAllOutermostParents(userId string, paginationState PaginationState) ([]Page, PaginationState, error) {
    authObject, err := dao.GetOAuth2TokenForIntegration(userId, "notion")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error getting OAuth2 token: %v", err)
        return nil, PaginationState{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to get OAuth2 token: %v", err)
    }

    accessToken, err := Decrypt(authObject.EncryptedAccessToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error decrypting access token: %v", err)
        return nil, PaginationState{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to decrypt access token: %v", err)
    }

    var allOutermostParents []Page

    // Start timer
    startTime := time.Now()

    for {
        loopStartTime := time.Now()
        outermostParents, newPaginationState, err := listOutermostParents(userId, paginationState, 100, accessToken)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, PaginationState{}, err
        }
        log.Printf("Time for listOutermostParents call: %v\n", time.Since(loopStartTime))

        allOutermostParents = append(allOutermostParents, outermostParents...)
        if newPaginationState.PageToken == "" {
            break
        }
        paginationState = newPaginationState
    }

    // End timer and log total time
    log.Printf("Total time for ListAllOutermostParents: %v\n", time.Since(startTime))

    return allOutermostParents, paginationState, nil
}

// calls the search function and filters results for only the ones that have no parents (outer files)
func listOutermostParents(userId string, paginationState PaginationState, pageSize int, accessToken string) ([]Page, PaginationState, error) {
    payload := map[string]interface{}{
        "query":     "",
        "page_size": pageSize,
        "filter": map[string]interface{}{
            "property": "object",
            "value":    "page",
        },
    }
    if paginationState.PageToken != "" {
        payload["start_cursor"] = paginationState.PageToken
    }

    payloadBytes, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error marshaling payload: %v", err)
        return nil, PaginationState{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal payload: %v", err)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.notion.com/v1/search", bytes.NewBuffer(payloadBytes))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error creating new request: %v", err)
        return nil, PaginationState{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to create new request: %v", err)
    }

    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Notion-Version", "2022-06-28")

    client := &http.Client{}

    // Start timer for HTTP request
    httpStartTime := time.Now()
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    log.Printf("Time for HTTP request: %v\n", time.Since(httpStartTime))

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error making request to Notion API: %v", err)
        return nil, PaginationState{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to make request to Notion API: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        log.Printf("Error response from Notion API: %s, Body: %s", resp.Status, string(body))
        return nil, PaginationState{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to search pages: %s", resp.Status)
    }

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error reading response body: %v", err)
        return nil, PaginationState{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to read response body: %v", err)
    }

    var searchResponse struct {
        Results    []Page `json:"results"`
        NextCursor string `json:"next_cursor"`
        HasMore    bool   `json:"has_more"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &searchResponse); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error unmarshaling response: %v", err)
        return nil, PaginationState{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal response: %v", err)
    }

    var outermostParents []Page
    for _, page := range searchResponse.Results {
        if (page.Parent.PageID == "" && page.Parent.DatabaseID == "") || page.Parent.Type == "workspace" {
            outermostParents = append(outermostParents, page)
        }
    }

    return outermostParents, PaginationState{PageToken: searchResponse.NextCursor}, nil
}

